# Simple <tr> Click Forcing Contained <a> Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get a simple invoke click to function like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ftwPS/6/  I am apparently missing something basic since this is not working when you click "CLICK".

```
$('tr').click(function() {
   $(this).find('a').click();
});​

<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        CLICK
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Not silly at all.  I double checked that before I posted and it's included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code to this;

```
$(function(){
    $('tr').click(function() {
        $(this).find('a')[0].click();
    });
});
​
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftwPS/22/)

**Edit**

Updated Answer

Comment: Yes I have seen this in other posts, but the problem I am having is I don't want to change the window location.  Ultimately my project is working with Google Maps and I have the pin locations rendering in a table.  When one of the hrefs is cicked it opens the info window for google map.  Now I want that same trigger when I click the <tr> the href is enclosed in.

Comment: You can use `window.open` instead which will open a popup window. This might be a solution?

Comment: This is a perfect solution to my initial problem.  Thank you.  Now if I can just get it to work with my Google Maps issue.

Answer (score 1):

Triggering a click event on the anchor tag will not do anything because the anchor tag has no `onclick` handler - the `href` attribute is an entirely different animal handled by the browser.

If you want to navigate to the anchor tag's `href` when you click the `td`, just do that instead:

```
$('tr').click(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ftwPS/15/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dispatchEvent`: http://jsfiddle.net/ftwPS/24/.

```
// Don't fire for the <a> itself, otherwise two windows will open
if($(e.target).is("a")) return;

var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("click");

// Assuming there is only one <a> inside
$(this).find("a").get(0).dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: This isn't cross browser safe? Older versions of IE don't have this `createEvent` I believe.

Comment: Either way, this did not trigger the event in Chrome.

Comment: @Help Inspire: It works for me now in Chrome. Not sure if it's cross-browser, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').click(function() {
   window.open($(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```